# Laout of the Row of the List

Tags: android-layout

```
 ----------------                                     -------------------
 |Name:          |                                   |Date:             |
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------
 | Orderid      |                |                   |                  |
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------
                                                     | Total:           |
                                                     -------------------
```

Can we make a layout as the one in the image in android.

I have tried out the following but it is not that smart which is looking in picture:-

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rl">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Name" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name" android:layout_above="@+id/ll" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="180dp" android:id="@+id/total" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Total" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CreationDate"></TextView>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/CreationDate" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Name" android:layout_marginTop="106dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/orderid" android:text="Order ID"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/businessname" android:text="BusinessName"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/desc" android:text="Desc"></TextView>
</TableRow>
<TextView android:layout_width="194dp" android:id="@+id/CreationDate" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CreationDate" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

//**you can make this view Like.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="TextView" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" >
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3" >
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Total" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can make this with any way.